# Как сделать ленту RSS?

Tags: xml, php, rss

Здравствуйте!

Опять появился вопрос: как сделать ленту rss? Вроде, все как сказано в инете сделала, прбовала сохранить в xml файл - пишется "ошибка разбора". Пробовала тот же файл сохранять в php - данные выходят, только ссылки не работают и нет окна для подписки. В общем, как только не переделывала код, вот он:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Канал новостей сайта ...ru</title>
<link>http://www...ru/</link>
<description>Справочники, сборники, энциклопедии - канал новостей</description>
<language>ru</language><br><br>

<?php
include "blocks/bd.php";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, text FROM bonus1 ORDER by 'id'");
if ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    do {
        printf("<item>

    <title1>%s</title1>

    <link>http://...ru/bonus2.php</link>
    <description>%s</description>
    <author>link@...ru</author><br>
    <guid>http://...ru/bonus2.php?page=%s</guid><br><br>
    </item>", $myrow['title'], $myrow['text'], $myrow['id']);
    } while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
}    
?>

</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do
{
printf("<item>

<title1>%s</title1>

<link>http://...ru/bonus2.php</link>
<description>%s</description>
<author>link@...ru</author><br>
<guid>http://...ru/bonus2.php?page=%s</guid><br><br>
</item>",$myrow['title'], $myrow['text'], $myrow['id']);
}   
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)); 
}
```

Нет Вы реально юзаете **do while** вместо **while**??? т.е. разницы для вас нет никакой

- **While** предусловие
- **Do/while** постусловие

При обработке инфы из БД лучше, да и постоянно используют while. т.к. сначала проверяют есть ли строка и потом только выводят.

```
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
$content .="<item>
             <title1>".$myrow['title']."</title1>
             <link>http://...ru/bonus2.php</link>
             <description>".$myrow['text']."</description>
             <author>link@...ru</author><br>
             <guid>http://...ru/bonus2.php?page=".$myrow['id']."</guid><br><br>
           </item>";  
echo $content;
```

Советую windows-1251 сменить на utf-8 потом меньше гемора будет.

Comment: Спасибо! А у меня то в коде ошибки есть? Мне важно знать причину, почему не работает. Незнаю, Do/while использует Попов(по его урокам училась).

Comment: попробуй мой код.

Ошибки то какие выскакивают, по идее должна выскочить ошибка того что **записи нет выводить нечего**. Чуть больше конкретики.


*Попов* ни о чем не говорит, не видел такого автора и не видел ни одной его книги, но если он там так пишет я бы выбросил книгу в печь!